# fail to apply as.factor function to several columns in R

Tags: r, lapply

Just now I learned that I can use "with" option to specify the columns but I still don't get that why the following function doesn't work.

```
> wealth_valid[,c(1,3:6)]<-lapply(wealth_valid[,c(1,3:6)], as.factor)
> str(wealth_valid)

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  257751 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Marital : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ Age     : int  53 63 36 42 60 59 62 46 54 50 ...
 $ Gender  : chr  "3" "3" "3" "3" ...
 $ Income  : chr  "4" "4" "4" "4" ...
 $ HMV     : chr  "5" "5" "5" "5" ...
 $ Owner   : chr  "6" "6" "6" "6" ...
 $ Networth: chr  "E" "G" "C" "F" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: This is literally the very first entry in the **data.table** [FAQ](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf). I suggest you read that document.

Comment: Try `wealth_valid[,7, with = F]`

Comment: Thx! It works for selecting a specific column. But I still don't figure out how to the lapply thing. It seems lapply doesn't work here

Comment: @gung Not according to the output from `str()` that the OP included in their question. It clearly says it's a data.table.

Comment: @joran, you're right. I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out the reason.I read the data with "fread" so he data is not dataframe format, after I transformed it, it works both lapply and wealth_valid[,7]